# How can I define PotsgreSQL table partitions using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using

- psycopg2(2.9.9)
- SQLAlchemy(2.0.22)
- PostgreSQL(16.0)

and I'm trying to create a SQLAlchemy model that generates a list partitioned table. I can use the following to define a table, BUT (see below)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, dialects
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('postgresql://test_user:test_password@localhost:5432/test_db')
Base = declarative_base()

class PartitionedTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'partitioned_table'

    __table_args__ = {
        'postgresql_partition_by': 'LIST (category)',
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    category = Column(String)
    value = Column(Integer)
```

How can I also define the actual partitions in the same piece of code? For example, I would like two partitions for `category` values of `'A'` and `'B'`. How can I define the partitions inside the SQLAlchemy model?

Comment: Can you share the the DDL that you are expecting to generate?

Comment: For example:
```
CREATE TABLE partitioned_table (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(255),
            category VARCHAR(255),
            value INTEGER,
            PARTITION BY LIST (category)
        );
        CREATE TABLE partitioned_table_a PARTITION OF partitioned_table FOR VALUES IN ('A');
```